# Adding a row to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am reading a file line by line and then adding specific lines to a dataframe. Here is an example of a line I would add to a dataframe:

ATOM    230  CA  GLU A  31      66.218 118.140   2.411  1.00 31.82           C

I have verified that my checks are ok, I think it has specifically to do with my rbind command. Thanks for your help!

Edit: The error is as follows, the output of the dataframe is:

```
Residue AtomCount SideChain XCoord  YCoord ZCoord
2       MET         1         A 62.935  97.579 30.223
21     <NA>         2         A 63.155  95.525 27.079
3      <NA>         3         A 65.289  96.895 24.308
```

It seems like it stops picking up the name of the residue..

The code I am using is:

```
get.positions <- function(sourcefile, chain_required = "A"){
positions = data.frame()
visited = list()
filedata <- readLines(sourcefile, n= -1)
for(i in 1: length(filedata)){
  input = filedata[i]
  id = substr(input,1,4)
  if(id == "ATOM"){
    type = substr(input,14,15)
      if(type == "CA"){
        #if there are duplicates it takes the first one
        residue = substr(input,18,20)
        type_of_chain = substr(input,22,22)
        atom_count = strtoi(substr(input, 23,26))
        if(atom_count >=1){
          if(type_of_chain == chain_required && !(atom_count %in% visited) ){
            position_string = trim(substr(input,30,54))
            position_string = lapply(unlist(strsplit(position_string," +")),as.numeric)
            positions<- rbind(positions, list(residue, atom_count, type_of_chain, position_string[[1]], position_string[[2]], position_string[[3]]))
            }
        }
      }
     }

    } 
        return (positions)
 }
```

Comment: (1) You haven't said what the problem is, (2) Once you discover that this code is _amazingly_ slow, try reading the first few sections of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) to see why that is, and how to fix it.

Comment: a way of debugging whether the variable holds correct information  or not  is to simply print  using `print(variable value)` and check.

Comment: Give us a very small sample set of data that illustrates your problem. For example, looking at your loop, I noticed that you split the string by the `+` character, but there are no plus characters in your sample input. Also, `strtoi` may not be doing what you think it does; if you pass it a floating point, it will return `NA`. Finally, what package did you get `trim` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In, the end, the following worked. First I made a much larger data frame, and then just replace specific rows (thank you Joran who linked me to the R inferno).

For the user that asked why I am splitting on a plus, your assumption is incorrect. The syntax is actually " +", that's a space-plus so that it's splitting on multiple spaces.Finally, as for the incorrect indices, I've finally figured out how to show the extra spaces on the form. Here is the correct original line, you will see the indices match.

```
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1      62.935  97.579  30.223  1.00 37.58           C
```

The R code that works, is as follows.

```
get.positions <- function(sourcefile, chain_required = "A"){
N <- 10^5
AACount <- 0
positions = data.frame(Residue=rep(NA, N),AtomCount=rep(NA, N),SideChain=rep(NA, N),XCoord=rep(NA, N),YCoord=rep(NA, N),ZCoord=rep(NA, N),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)     

visited = list()
filedata <- readLines(sourcefile, n= -1)
for(i in 1: length(filedata)){
  input = filedata[i]
  id = substr(input,1,4)
  if(id == "ATOM"){
    type = substr(input,14,15)
      if(type == "CA"){
        #if there are duplicates it takes the first one
        residue = substr(input,18,20)
        type_of_chain = substr(input,22,22)
        atom_count = strtoi(substr(input, 23,26))
        if(atom_count >=1){
          if(type_of_chain == chain_required && !(atom_count %in% visited) ){
            visited <- c(visited, atom_count)
            AACount <- AACount + 1
            position_string = trim(substr(input,30,54))
            position_string = lapply(unlist(strsplit(position_string," +")),as.numeric)
            #print(input)
            positions[AACount,]<- c(residue, atom_count, type_of_chain, position_string[[1]], position_string[[2]], position_string[[3]])
            }
        }
      }
  }

} 
positions<-positions[1:AACount,]
return (positions)
```

}

Comment: It's perfectly OK to accept your own answer to your question. If this is solved, then I recommend marking it as accepted to remove it from the "unanswered" queue of R questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code with that data I got `type=="LU"` (so it failed the `type=="CA"` test) and the rest of processing never got accomplished. I think you may need to change the indices to

```
type = substr(input,10,11)
```

Fixing that problem brings up others, and its going to be very difficult to fix all the problems since the goal is not clearly stated, but it suggests that you edit your code and data so it's reproducible. This could be a reproducible input/execution method:

```
get.positions(textConnection("ATOM 230 CA GLU A 31 66.218 118.140 2.411 1.00 31.82 C") )
```